# nVidia GTX 570 power supply

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

The GTX 570 card requieres aditional power from the power supply, it has 1x 6-PIN and 1x 8-PIN, but in the official documentation there is stated that it requieres 2x 6-PIN.

So what PS should I buy: 2x 6-PIN or 1x 6-PIN and 1x 8-PIN ?

Comment: Where are you getting this information, provide the links, purchase whatever the card you actually have requires to function.  It seems like you are getting reference design requirements confused with actual product requirements.

Comment: You don't tend to get 6-PIN only cables they tend to be 6+2-PIN if you like.. so you can either use them as 8-PIN or 6-PIN but yes Ramhound is right can we have some more details, maybe the manufacture and model of the card exactly so we can do some digging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8-pin PCIe power connectors can handle higher power demands than the 6-pin.  The two additional pins in the 8-pin are simply 2 more ground wires.

The video adapter needs 2x 6-pin to run, but can accept an 8-pin plug as well (for compatibility sake).

So, from the video card's point of view, it doesn't matter if you use a 6-pin or an 8-pin PCIe from the PSU.  From a PSU point of view, you should prefer one with the 8-pin connector, just in case you ever need that extra power it can handle (in the future).